# "Par exemple" utilisé comme contradiction?

Tags: québec

Au Québec, nous utilisons souvent le terme *Par exemple* pour signifier une contradiction (?).

D'où cela vient-il? Puisque la définition d'*Exemple* est loin de vouloir dire cela.

Exemple:

> J'ai réussi le niveau dix, mais **par exemple** je n'ai jamais réussi le vingtième.
>   J'ai réussir à m'endormir, mais je dois dire que j'ai eu de la misère **par exemple**.

Tiré du [dictionnaire québécois](http://www.dictionnaire-quebecois.com/definitions-p.html) :

> **Par exemple** : Au Québec on utilise l'expression "par exemple" dans les situations suivantes : [1] pour signaler l'étonnement : "comme c'est cher par exemple ! ; [2] à titre d'adverbe, dans le même sens que : ainsi ; de cette façon ; [3] pour illustrer une pensée (ex : par exemple, si je te donne un dollar…).

Comment: *Ça par exemple !* est par exemple souvent présent dans les bandes dessinées. Je ne dirais pas que cet emploi est spécifique au québecois, mais il sonne en tout cas un peu vieillot en français de France.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans les deux exemples cités, la contradiction *apparente* est introduite par la conjonction **mais** plutôt que par la locution **par exemple**.
Si on supprime **par exemple** de ces phrases, le sens n'est pas modifié :

> J'ai réussi le niveau dix, mais je n'ai jamais réussi le vingtième.
>   J'ai réussi à m'endormir, mais je dois dire que j'ai eu de la misère.

Comment: Bien vu, alors "Par exemple" n'est qu'un adverbe. Que représente-t-il? Quels locutions adverbiales pourraient le remplacer?

Comment: @Sifu: On pourrait remplacer par « évidemment », « comme on peut s'en douter », « pour donner un exemple » ...